# Test Driven Development in Swift

Tags: swift, tdd, sqlite.swift

I'm playing around a bit in Swift and after installing some external frameworks I decided that before I go any further with this project I'll write some tests.

I first imported my model class into my test class :

```
import XCTest
import Company

class CompaniesTest: XCTestCase {
...
```

However I got an error : "No such Module Company"

I then went to that model and added it to the target Mobile CRMTest:

[image]

But then in my model Class I got the same Error : "No such Module SQLite"

```
import Foundation
import SQLite
import SwiftyJSON

class Company  {
```

for the SQLite.swift framework I'm using (installed using CocoaPods)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I'd check to see if the SQLite framework is included in the test target as well as the application target.

Comment: It wasn't... but I couldn't include it because it would give a compiler error then. After rebuilding the project all is fine